# Failed to include boost on macos

Tags: c++

I successfully installed boost on my mac, but I can't include it in my code.

**Installation**

```
brew install boost
```

**Code**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string server = "www.stroustrup.com";
    enter code here
    std::string request = "GET http://" + server + "/C++.html 
HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " + server + "\r\n\r\n";
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s{server, "http"};
    s << request;
    std::regex pat{R"((http://)?www([./#\+-]\w*)+)"};
    std::smatch m;
    for (std::string l; getline(s, l);)
        if (std::regex_search(l, m, pat))
            std::cout << m[0] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please don't post text as images. How am I going to copy it to my editor?

Comment: How are we ever going to get telepathic compilers that build the program you want instead of the program you asked for if we can't get simple OCR compilers right?

Comment: Why do you need to copy my code to your editor, if the error is in #include? Ok, I will add it.

Comment: @Kate, you are right there is no need to be able to copy the code in this case but you might not always be able to know what someone needs to answer your questions. Actually in this case what is much more important is what your compile command is or your project settings in Xcode? Where did brew install the headers? However for several reasons like copy pasting, readability, search indexing it would be preferable to use text as much as possible and only use image if it is the only way. Have a look at Matthieu's answer (which assumes you are using Xcode).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you did install boost, you still need to add the headers to your application.

Go to your target properties -> Build Settings -> Header Search Path and add `/usr/local/include`. That's where it should have been installed IIRC.